# vue-cli app are not watching file changes?

Tags: vue.js, websocket, vue-cli-3

i have create a vue-cli app (vue create app). when i run (npm run serve) the server is open to (http://localhost:8081/) but it's dose't watch file changes. if i changes any thing i have to refresh the browser to see the changes. it's show me some error in console. [image]

why the socket trying to connect with this ip (http://192.168.0.108/)

Comment: When you start the application, what are the values for `Local` and `Network ` URLs that the App runs at?

Comment: the app run at - Local:   http://localhost:8081/  - Network: http://192.168.0.108:8081/  https://prnt.sc/rv9ffn

Comment: Is it possible that other Vue applications are running as well? If you could stop them all and try to start this particular application. You can use `vue ui` to do this.

Comment: no other app are running. i restart my pc for test